# Perl cut characters up to revolving regex, print to end of line

Tags: regex, perl, cut

I have this data, where i want to cut out the date, and print everything from the Initials to the end. 
I mapped the initials.

```
30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Charlie Brown: BJ: Bloomberg Runs
30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Charlie Brown: DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
30th Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Yeltsin: Cortese's ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs issue
30th Mar 2020 6:43:28 pm Charlie Brown: yeap
31st Mar 2020 4:11:22 am Ishtar Johnson: VK : RE: XS2018777099 & XS2018777172 - INC1018491954
31st Mar 2020 6:31:17 am Tommy Boy: NW: RE: SABSM 6.125 YTW - INC1018495843
31st Mar 2020 7:26:40 am Tommy Boy: AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
31st Mar 2020 7:45:36 am Tommy Boy: JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

Here is the code -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ") ;
my ( $team_regex ) = map {qr /$_/} join "|", map {quotemeta} @team;

my @orderdTeam ;
my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
        #$line =~ /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
        $line = /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
        print "$line\n";

}
close $fh;
```

For some reason i get thse uninitialzed errors.

```
johnswal@NYKPWM2037968 ~
$ ./cut_date_symphony.pl fooberry
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./cut_date_symphony.pl line 14, <$fh> line 8.
```

The commented line just prints out the whole line - it does not cut out the date or time

```
#$line =~ /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
```

So this is what I am looking for. "Tommy Boy NW:" and "Ishtar Johnson VK:" are part of our team, but from Europe. Only the American team members in the map array "@team_regex" tickets will be displayed. 
and the time and date will be cut out of the line.

```
BJ: Bloomberg Runs
DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

Comment: The commented line does not cut any characters out  - it prints the whole ine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 14 is this line:

```
$line = /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
```

The match operator (`/.../`) works on either the variable that is bound to it using the `=~` operator or `$_` if no such variable is given. You don't use `=~`, so the match operator tries to match against `$`. And `$_` contains no data, so Perl gives you the "undefined value" warning that you see.

I think you want to match the regex against the contents of `$line`. So you need to use `=~` instead of `=` - as in your commented out line.

```
$line =~ /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
```

But in a comment above you explain that you've commented this out because:

> The commented line does not cut any characters out - it prints the whole ine

And of course it does that because you've written no code to change `$line` in any way. But what you want is in `$1` after the match, so print that instead.

```
$line =~ /($team_regex .*)/s  ;
print $1;
```

But the regex variables like `$1` only get set on a successful match, so it's important to check the match works before printing them out. You can do that by putting the match operator in an `if` statement.

```
if ($line =~ /($team_regex .*)/s) {
  print $1;
}
```

**Update:** Oh, and that doesn't work as the team codes in your data are followed by a colon, not a space (as your regex assumes). So change it to this:

```
if ($line =~ /($team_regex:.*)/s) {
  print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following code snippet for demonstration how to achieve desired result

I believe that regex for team should be formed in a different way. Skip all records not matching regex. Then substitute first 5 *data columns* to nothing and print result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ");

my $re_team = join ': |', @team;

my $filename = shift;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    next unless /$re_team/;
    s/^(\S+ ){5}//;
    say;
}

close $fh;
```

Input data

```
30th Mar 2020 5:53:18 pm Charlie Brown: BJ: Bloomberg Runs
30th Mar 2020 5:53:27 pm Charlie Brown: DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
30th Mar 2020 6:42:43 pm Boris Yeltsin: Cortese's ICE logs is for the Bloomberg Runs issue
30th Mar 2020 6:43:28 pm Charlie Brown: yeap
31st Mar 2020 4:11:22 am Ishtar Johnson: VK : RE: XS2018777099 & XS2018777172 - INC1018491954
31st Mar 2020 6:31:17 am Tommy Boy: NW: RE: SABSM 6.125 YTW - INC1018495843
31st Mar 2020 7:26:40 am Tommy Boy: AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
31st Mar 2020 7:45:36 am Tommy Boy: JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

Output

```
Charlie Brown: BJ: Bloomberg Runs
Charlie Brown: DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
Tommy Boy: AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
Tommy Boy: JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

Substitute `s/^(\S+ ){5}//;` to `s/^(\S+ ){7}//;` to get following output

```
BJ: Bloomberg Runs
DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

Of cause the code can be written as

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ");

my $re_team = join ': |', @team;

my $filename = shift;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

/($re_team)/ && say /($1.*)/  while <$fh>;

close $fh
```

Or even this way

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ");

my $re_team = join ': |', @team;

/($re_team)/ && say /($1.*)/  while <>;
```

Output

```
BJ: Bloomberg Runs
DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661
AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102
JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380
```

If it is desired to capture data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ");

my $re_team = join ': |', @team;

my @data;

/($re_team)/ && push @data,/($1.*)/  while <>;

say Dumper(\@data);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'BJ: Bloomberg Runs',
          'DS: ICE DATA = INC1018483661',
          'AP: RE: Rolling 7yrs - INC1018497102',
          'JK: RE: Chris White books - INC1018497380'
        ];
```